# Are $X$ and $Y-E(Y|X) $ independent?

Tags: probability

The question is quite simple: if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables (with unknown distribution, possibly independent), are $X$ and $Z=Y-E(Y|X)$ independent?

Thinking about the conditional expectation as a projection, this might sound reasonable. Moreover, if $(X,Y)$ follows a multivariate normal distribution, then the proposition is true (direct computations). However, I could not build a general proof, so the normal case could be a very special case.

Comment: Normal is indeed very special, because for multivariate normal uncorrelated implies independent.  But this is not the case in general.  Counterexamples to independence are very easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated, but not necessarily independent. We know
$$\begin{align}
E(XZ) & =E(XY)-E(X\cdot E(Y|X))\\
& = E(XY)-EE(XY|X)\\
& = E(XY)-E(XY)\\
& = 0 = EX\cdot EZ
\end{align}$$
So $X$,$Z$ are uncorrelated. This accounts for the intuitive conclusion followed from a projection comprehension. But in general they are not independent. See the following example: let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ be the counting measure. Set $X(1)=X(2)=0,X(3)=X(4)=1$ and $Y(1)=Y(2)=Y(3)=0,Y(4)=1$. So $Z(1)=Z(2)=0,Z(3)=-1/2,Z(4)=+1/2$. In this case $X=0$ and $Z=-1/2$ cannot hold simultaneously, showing that $X,Z$ are not independent.

Comment: It might be kinder if you added something like "so $Z(1)=Z(2)=0, Z(3)=-1/2,Z(4)=+1/2$"

Comment: @arctictern Obviously. It seems I haven't wake up yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let $Y=XW$ be the product of two independent random variables. Then 
$$ Z=Y-E(Y|X)=XW - E(XW|X)=XW - X E(W)=X (W-E(W))$$ which in general is not independent from $X$.